# Interactive pie charts: Associate a click event with a slice of a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, pie-chart, interactive

I am working on a toy pie chart using d3.js

My pie chart has 3 slices. I would like to know whether it is possible invoke a function whenever a slice of the pie-chart is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function animateFirstStep(){
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()                            
      .attr("d",arc1);  
        /* .attr("d", arc2)
        .style("fill", "black"); */

       /*  .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", 1);   */         
};
function animateSecondStep(){
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .ease("elastic")
      .duration(1500)
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.trName); });              
        /* .style("stroke", "white")
        .style("stroke-width", 0); */   
};
  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data.HubActivity.hubWorkloadList))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.trName); })
      .on("mouseover", animateFirstStep)
      .on("mouseout", animateSecondStep);
```

I think this would be of some help ... when you hover the mouse on any arc function will be fired you can change it to click